# template doesnot exist errror in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi I am beginner and I am trying to do a sign up login and logout pages but I am getting template doesnot exist error
my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username'])
                return render (request,'templates/accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Username is already taken!'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render (request,'templates/accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Password does not match!'})
    else:
        return render(request,'templates/accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password = request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render (request,'templates/accounts/login.html', {'error':'Username or password is incorrect!'})
    else:
        return render(request,'templates/accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('home')







please help me out thanks in advance
```

error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/signup/
templates/accounts/signup.html

my template configuration in setting.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


my folder structure 
    project name : 
    -mysite
      -accounts(app name)
    - templates
      - accounts
        -base.html
        -login.html
        -signup.html
```

this is the correct structure of my project if I gave templates/accounts/signup.html also it is not working please help me

Comment: show us your templates configuration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: @iklinac I have updated my template configuration in my question can you please help me ?

Comment: folder structure is not very clear but I would guess you should omit templates from your path  in render function so it is just accounts/signup.html

Comment: @iklinac see I had updated the folder structure clearly and also tried all the ways please see once and help me

Comment: @iklinac I am not understanding where I did wrong I tried many ways like accounts/signup.html and templates/accounts/signup.html and only signup.html but not working it will be helpful for me if you can guide me thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the path of your templates directory in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then in your views remove `templates` from the template path in render. Example -

```
return render(request,'accounts/signup.html')
```